# Impossible WHERE condition in ON clause

Tags: mysql

I've got a problem on mysql where I get an 'Impossible WHERE condition' based on a condition in an `ON` clause in a `LEFT JOIN`. I have this bug in mysql version `5.1.47` but not in `5.1.52`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.magic_table1 (
    id int primary key,
    val int,
    key (val)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.magic_table2 (
    id int primary key,
    val int,
    key (val)
);

insert into test.magic_table1 values ( 1, 1 );
insert into test.magic_table2 values ( 0, 0 );

/* explain */
select *
from test.magic_table1 m1
left join test.magic_table2 m2
on m1.id = m2.val
and m1.val = 0
where m1.id = 1;
```

On MySQL 5.1.52, this returns:

```
1 | 1 | NULL | NULL
```

On MySQL 5.1.47 returns the empty set.

Is this supposed to work as I imagine, or is there something wrong about the way this query is written? This was a hard thing to track down because of the difference in the way MySQL reacts in different versions.

Comment: . . You have some other problem.  This returns one row in SQL Fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9a41/1).  Note that SQL Fiddle dedups column names, so you don't get all the columns.

Comment: That query is supposed to return only one row. As for the columns, you're right, but if you run it on a real MySQL instance, it will work as expected. The problem behavior I saw was returning no rows at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one bug reported in mysql.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=53334

Go through it. May be of some help for you.